# Powershell ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the owner of a process using this code:

```
(Get-WmiObject -class win32_process | where{$_.ProcessName -eq 'explorer.exe'}).getowner() | Foreach-Object user | out-string
```

This works great under Windows 8 but in Windows 7 I get this message:

> ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'Process'. Cannot convert the "user" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock". At C:\Program Files (x86)\Advanced Monitoring Agent GP\scripts\9660.ps1:1 char: 108 + (Get-WmiObject -class win32_process | where{$_.ProcessName -eq 'explorer.exe' }).getowner() | Foreach-Object <<<< user | out-string + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], Parameter BindingException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand

Answer (score 2):

Please modify the user iterator and try on both 7 and 8:

```
(Get-WmiObject -class win32_process | 
    where{$_.ProcessName -eq 'explorer.exe'}).getowner() | 
    Foreach-Object {$_.user } | out-string
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with line breaks:

```
gwmi win32_process | where ProcessName -Match "explorer" | foreach {$_.GetOwner().User | Out-String}
```

Or *without*

```
gwmi win32_process | where ProcessName -Match "explorer" | foreach {$_.GetOwner().User}
```

Remember to wrap your foreach 'script' inside `{}`'s.

For the sake of completeness I'll say this was done with Powershell 3.0, hence no `{}` for the `where-object` cmdlet, and no `$_` for the ProcessName property.